# How to unit test a program that returns a dataframe using cursor.description after querying snowflake using pytest?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mocking, pytest

I am trying to test get_data.py using test_get_data.py but I am getting an exception at `result=get_data(mock_cursor, query)`:

```
AttributeError: ("'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'", 'Failed in reading from table').
```

The scripts are below:

*get_data.py*

```
import pandas as pd

def get_data(cur, query):
    cur.execute(query)
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(), columns=[li.name for li in cur.description])
    return data_df
```

*test_get_data.py*

```
def test_get_data():
   mock_cursor = MagicMock()

   test_data = [(1, 'Tim'), (2, 'Scott'), (3, 'Clay')]
   mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = test_data

   columns_info = ['id','name']
   mock_cursor.description = columns_info

   query = "SELECT * FROM users"
   result = get_data(mock_cursor, query)

   mock_cursor.execute.assert_called_once_with(query)

   expected_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns=["id", "name"])
   pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(result, expected_df)
```

Edit:

I was doing some testing and found that the issue is with `columns=[li.name for li in cur.description]`. The below test case passes (notice I have removed the above line):

*get_data.py*

```
import pandas as pd

def get_data(cur, query):
    cur.execute(query)
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
    return data_df
```

*test_get_data.py*

```
def test_get_data():
   mock_cursor = MagicMock()

   test_data = [(1, 'Tim'), (2, 'Scott'), (3, 'Clay')]
   mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = test_data


   query = "SELECT * FROM users"
   result = get_data(mock_cursor, query)

   mock_cursor.execute.assert_called_once_with(query)

   expected_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
   pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(result, expected_df)
```

So, I ran the following code by connecting to snowflake and executing a query:

```
cursor.execute(query)
desc = cursor.description
```

```
print(desc) 
>> [ResultSetMetadata(name='id', <<some other metadata here>>),ResultSetMetadata(name='name', <<some other metadata here>>)]

print(type(desc))
>> class 'list'
```

I tried putting this to my test_get_data.py but it throws *ResultSetMetadata not defined*. How can I replicate this?

```
columns_info = [ResultSetMetadata(name='id', <<some other metadata here>>),ResultSetMetadata(name='name', <<some other metadata here>>)]
mock_cursor.description = columns_info
```